# Missing eth-based USDT tokens on coin.space wallet

Tags: transactions, usdt

One of our customers tried to pay for service using USDT. The transaction can be found in etherscan but the amount is not in my boss's coin.space wallet.

This is the tx ID: 0xc25213461073b67a5ed20acb98a74af63d755d5c4d3aa66545d31c1aa335c09b

Here's the [direct link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc25213461073b67a5ed20acb98a74af63d755d5c4d3aa66545d31c1aa335c09b) as well:

And this is his coin.space eth-based USDT wallet address: 0x5ba8a58ca489abd345a58f3bdabc3d48b0f3b200

I have already created a support ticket in coin.space but still waiting for their response. If someone can give me some insight on why the tokens were missing, I would be really grateful as my job security is at stake.

I'm 100% certain that the tokens were sent from an eth-based USDT wallet in Binance since the customer sent a screenshot. I'm also 100% certain that our wallet address is an eth-based USDT wallet in coin.space

Thank you in advance whoever can help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the USDT has been transffered to the address and it is there already in ethereum blockchain. If your wallet does not show USDT value either your wallet does not have USDT contract imported or it does not support ethereum.
Try importing USDT contract to the wallet. USDT contract address for ethereum is `0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7`. Also you can take the seed from this wallet or copy private key and import in either metamask or trust wallet, where it will be shown after you enable eth-USDT in those wallet or import eth-USDT contract.